# KDB\Q: How to run an iterative union join from within a ticker function?

Tags: kdb

I am trying to run an iterative union join on a table from within a tick function according to the kdb tick architecture as follows:

```
table1:([]time:`timespan$();sym:`symbol$();var1:`float$());

if[not system"t";system"t 1000";
    .z.ts:{
        table2: ...
        table1:table1 uj table2 / throws non descriptive error
        `table1 uj table2 / throws type error
    }
```

non descriptive error:

> 'table1
>   [0]  ()

I am trying to maintain a local table that keeps the last 500 or so rows (with dynamic columns) in order to run further processing.
However I can't seem to update the table from within the tick function.
How should one implement this functionality?
Thanks

Comment: Isn't this the same as the other question you asked? There's a few issues in your code snippet: 1. Are you trying to do the union join twice or are you just doing that for display purposes? 2. Do you not have semi-colons at the end of your statements or are you again just not showing them for display purposes? 3. You can't reference a table by name when using union join `uj` you have to reference the table by value. In other words you can't have a backtick in front of the table name, you have to use `table1:table1 uj table2;` and note that this creates a local table not a global.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting 'table1 as an error as it is not defined locally within `.z.ts`. In kdb if there is local assignment to a specific variable within a function, kdb references that variable locally within the function. In the example of `table1` you assign it locally within `.z.ts` but then attempt to reference `table1` which you assigned globally outside of `.z.ts`. To fix your issue you must assign `table1` globally within `.z.ts` like so `table1::table1 uj table2`.

```
table1:([]time:`timespan$();sym:`symbol$();var1:`float$());

if[not system"t";system"t 1000";
    .z.ts:{
        table2: ...
        table1::table1 uj table2
```

Answer (score 3):

As a general rule,

> *if a signal is returned that **is not one of the [basic errors](https://code.kx.com/v2/basics/errors/)**, then it is due to scoping*.

This assumes you are not giving variables names from the given list, which is the best practice for this reason. If you are following that practice, you know that if a variable name is returned, it's due to a scoping issue.

Re: scoping, kdb does not possess lexical scoping, further details on the scoping in kdb can be found [here](https://code.kx.com/q4m3/6_Functions/#631-defining-local-and-global-variables) and [here](https://code.kx.com/q4m3/12_Workspace_Organization/). However as Matt has detailed, this is due to the kdb parser being conflicted in the local/global mixed assignments